# driver instance in null in test classes

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

I am using testng+webdriver & initializing browser in following way-

```
public class base{
    private WebDriver driver;
    @Test
    public void launch(){
        System.out.println("In base class");
        driver = new FirefoxDriver();
    }
    public WebDriver getdriver(){
        return driver;
    }
}
```

and then test classes are like-

```
public class test extends base{
    WebDriver driver;
    @BeforeClass
    public void init(){
        driver = getdriver(); //getdriver method from base class
    }
    @Test   
    public void test1(){
        driver.get("http://www.yahoo.co.in"); //null pointer exception here
    }
}
```

But in test class i am getting null pointer exception as driver instance in null.
Any reason for driver is null in test classes?
Is there any way to launch only one browser at beginning of execution & close at end without using static?

Comment: Why do you want to avoid static variables?  This seems like a potential candidate for a singleton.

Comment: I am creating result xml from code. On using static & parallel execution static driver is causing problems. It is overwriting result of one test in xml of another test.

Answer (score 0):

Remove @Test from launch and call launch from within  getdriver. And it seems you can do the same thing in launch/ getdriver as:

```
public WebDriver getDriver(){
    return new FirefoxDriver();
}
```

OR

```
private WebDriver driver;
public void launch(){
    System.out.println("In base class");
    driver = new FirefoxDriver();
}
public WebDriver getDriver(){
    launch();
    return driver;
}
```

Comment: In this case whenever i call getdriver() from any test class it will open new browser instance. I want to open browser only once. Is it possible to do this without using static driver instance?

Comment: This is what my answer does... it will open a browser instance in getdriver and will return that instance since new is called only once. If its opening more then once then you are doing something wrong in your code...